# Как открыть файл в бинарном виде IOS 15.2 Swift 5.5

Tags: swift, binary-file

пытаюсь считать файл с айфона (физ. и сим.) и не получается, на сим. не могу даже файл выбрать, а на физ. выбираю файл и при чтении отвечает

```
The file "myfile" couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
```

Начал гуглить, инфы не нашел, как предоставить разрешение на просмотр файла, код как беру файл и его путь чуть ниже:

```
.fileImporter(
        isPresented: $openfile,
        allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]
    ) { result in
        do {
            let selectedFile = try result.get()
            print(selectedFile.absoluteURL)

            do {
                // Get the raw data from the file.
                let rawData: Data = try Data(contentsOf: selectedFile.absoluteURL)
                
            } catch {
                // Couldn't read the file.
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return nil
            }

        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае помогло `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource`

Результат:

```
let selectedFile = try result.get() // get path to file

                do {
                    // get access to open file
                    if selectedFile.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                        let path = selectedFile.path
                        let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
                        print(data) // array bytes
                        selectedFile.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                    }

                } catch {
                    // Couldn't read the file.
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
```

Эпл вики о этой фиче https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso